# How to write API action method that would accept a file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-3.0, asp.net-apicontroller

I am trying to write an API endpoint that would allow a user to send a file to my server using Asp.NET Core 3.1.

I have the following action method that needs to respond to the client's request and process the file validation and store the file.

```
[HttpPost, Route("api/store")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Store([FromBody] MultipartFormDataContent content)
{
    // Validate the file, store it.

    return Ok();
}
```

I am trying to send the file from the client-side like this

```
using HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

var multiForm = new MultipartFormDataContent();
multiForm.Add(new StringContent("1/12/1.jpg"), "custom_file_name");
FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead("1.jpg");
multiForm.Add(new StreamContent(fs), "file", "1.jpg");

// send request to API
var url = "https://localhost:123/api/store";
var response = await client.PostAsync(url, multiForm);
```

But the server returns `HTTP Code 404 Not Found`.

How can I correctly tweak the `Store` method above so it accepts the file being sent by the client?

Comment: Do you have a `[Route("...")]` attribute on your controller?

Comment: Yes, my controller is decorated with `[ApiController, Route("api/[controller]")]`. I even added a `HttpGet` method on the same controller and i was able to get to it.

Comment: can you post your complete controller class and implementation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't include `api/` in the action method route. The controller's route is already prefixed with `api`. Also, `api/[controller]` means the controller route will be `api/ControllerName`, then your action will be `api/ControllerName/store`.

If your controller class is named `ThingsController` then its route is `api/things`, and your `Store` action should be `api/things/store`.

You don't need to use both `HttpPost` and `Route` attributes on an action. The `Route` attribute accepts all HTTP verbs, so use one or the other (typically just `HttpPost` or whatever HTTP verb you will be handling with the action method. So:

```c#
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ThingsController : ControllerBase
{
    // POST api/things/store
    [HttpPost("store")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Store([FromBody] MultipartFormDataContent content)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Also, the controller should be using `IFormFile` to deal with file uploads in your controller. The documentation is here:

### [Upload files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.1#file-upload-scenarios) .

Your controller would accept a `IFormFile files` parameter rather than `MultipartFormDataContent content`.

**Example from MSDN, adapted to your action**

```c#
[HttpPost("store")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Store(List<IFormFile> files)
{
    // Get total size
    long size = files.Sum(f => f.Length);

    foreach (var formFile in files)
    {
        if (formFile.Length > 0)
        {
            // Gets a temporary file name
            var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

            // Creates the file at filePath and copies the contents
            using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
            {
                await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }
        }
    }

    // Process uploaded files
    // Don't rely on or trust the FileName property without validation.

    return Ok(new { count = files.Count, size, filePath });
}
```

If you're dealing with a single file, you can just pass `IFormFile file` instead of a list, and get rid of the looping in the action method.

I have **not** tested this code myself, wrote it on a mobile device. Hopefully it solves the problem though.